# How can I add custom imagery to a mapbox project?

Tags: mapbox

I have a file that was output from Pix4D as an mbtile, along with the actual image files in the google earth tiles folder, I want to use them as the base map in a mapbox project but wondering how I accomplish this?

It seems confusing if I am supposed to do something with them in Tilemill, or if I just upload .tif files to the mapbox project, or something else.

Anyone have a simple walk through of how to accomplish adding your own imagery to the mapbox base map?

Comment: maybe this helps? https://www.mapbox.com/blog/processing-drone-imagery/

Answer (score 1):

@ user25644:

You may go to mapbox website and click the project icon:
[image]

Then Add a New Project to import the files:
[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That seems to be for importing an overlay whereas I am trying to import basemap imagery (MBTiles)